# reducing using instance variable to decrease the use of memory

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to do the [Algorithm](https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/percolation/specification.php) programming assignment of Princeton , and I met a problem about the memory test. The assignment requires us run the percolation program N times and find the medium of the result, and I write a percolationtest.java and for each time, I create an instance variable, it worked, but use too much memory, and the instructor suggests me to use local variable, but I don't know how. Can some one help me and give me some advice, I really appreciate it.

```
public class PercolationStats {
private int N, T, totalSum;
private double []fraction;
private int []count;
public PercolationStats(int N, int T) {
    if (N <= 0 || T <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else {
        this.N = N;
        this.T = T;
        count = new int [T];
        totalSum = N*N;
        fraction = new double[T];


    int randomX, randomY;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    Percolation perc = new Percolation(N);
    while (true) {
        if (perc.percolates()) {
            fraction[i] = (double) count[i]/totalSum;
            break;
        }
        randomX = StdRandom.uniform(1, N+1);
        randomY = StdRandom.uniform(1, N+1);
        if (perc.isOpen(randomX, randomY)) continue;
        else {
             perc.open(randomX, randomY);
             count[i]++;
        }
    }
    }
    }
} // perform T independent experiments on an N-by-N grid
public double mean() {
    double totalFraction = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        totalFraction += fraction[i];
    }
    return totalFraction/T;
} // sample mean of percolation threshold
public double stddev() {
    double u = this.mean();
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        sum += (fraction[i] - u) * (fraction[i] - u);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(sum/(T-1));
} // sample standard deviation of percolation threshold
public double confidenceLo() {
    double u = this.mean();
    double theta = this.stddev();
    double sqrtT = Math.sqrt(T);
    return u-1.96*theta/sqrtT;
} // low  endpoint of 95% confidence interval
public double confidenceHi() {
    double u = this.mean();
    double theta = this.stddev();
    double sqrtT = Math.sqrt(T);
    return u+1.96*theta/sqrtT;
} // high endpoint of 95% confidence interval

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int N = 200;
   int T = 100;
   if (args.length == 1) N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   else if (args.length == 2) {
       N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       T = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); }

   PercolationStats a = new PercolationStats(N, T);
   System.out.print("mean                    = ");
   System.out.println(a.mean());
   System.out.print("stddev                  = ");
   System.out.println(a.stddev());
   System.out.print("95% confidence interval = ");
   System.out.print(a.confidenceLo()); 
   System.out.print(", ");
   System.out.println(a.confidenceHi());
```

} 
}

```
public class Percolation {
private boolean[][] site;
private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;
private int N;

public Percolation(int N) {
    if (N < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else {
        site = new boolean[N + 2][N + 2];
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
            site[0][j] = true;
            site[N + 1][j] = true;
        }
        uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF((N + 2) * (N + 2));
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            uf.union(0, i);
        }
        this.N = N;
    }
}

public void open(int i, int j) {
    if (i > N || i < 1 || j > N || j < 1)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    else {
        if (!site[i][j]) {
            site[i][j] = true;
            if (site[i - 1][j]) {
                uf.union((N + 2) * (i - 1) + j, (N + 2) * i + j);
            }
            if (site[i + 1][j]) {
                uf.union((N + 2) * i + j, (N + 2) * (i + 1) + j);
            }
            if (site[i][j + 1]) {
                uf.union((N + 2) * i + (j + 1), (N + 2) * i + j);
            }
            if (site[i][j - 1]) {
                uf.union((N + 2) * i + (j - 1), (N + 2) * i + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean isOpen(int i, int j) {
    if (i > N || i < 1 || j > N || j < 1)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    else
        return site[i][j];
}

public boolean isFull(int i, int j) {
    if (i > N || i < 1 || j > N || j < 1)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    else
        return site[i][j] && (i == 1 || uf.connected((N + 2) * i + j, 0));
}

public boolean percolates() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (this.isFull(N, i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

}

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I just post it.

Answer (score 1):

Added meanValue instance variable to keep mean value and replaced it in multiple places where you used to call mean() method which was over head to calculate again and again. Also modified "int[] count" as local variable which you were not using outside the constructor. post your "Percolation" and "StdRandom" classes for more optimization of code. you can run this code and test, it should reduce the runtime than yours.

```
public class PercolationStats {

private int N, T, totalSum;
private double []fraction;
private double meanValue;

public PercolationStats(int N, int T) {



    if (N <= 0 || T <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    else {
        this.N = N;
        this.T = T;
        int [] count = new int [T];
        totalSum = N*N;
        fraction = new double[T];


    int randomX, randomY;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
    Percolation perc = new Percolation(N);
    while (true) {
        if (perc.percolates()) {
            fraction[i] = (double) count[i]/totalSum;
            break;
        }
        randomX = StdRandom.uniform(1, N+1);
        randomY = StdRandom.uniform(1, N+1);
        if (perc.isOpen(randomX, randomY)) continue;
        else {
             perc.open(randomX, randomY);
             count[i]++;
        }
    }
    }
    }
}
// perform T independent experiments on an N-by-N grid
public double mean() {
    double totalFraction = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        totalFraction += fraction[i];
    }
    meanValue = totalFraction/T;
    return meanValue;
} // sample mean of percolation threshold
public double stddev() {
    double u = meanValue;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        sum += (fraction[i] - u) * (fraction[i] - u);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(sum/(T-1));
} // sample standard deviation of percolation threshold
public double confidenceLo() {
    double u = meanValue;
    double theta = this.stddev();
    double sqrtT = Math.sqrt(T);
    return u-1.96*theta/sqrtT;
} // low  endpoint of 95% confidence interval
public double confidenceHi() {
    double u = meanValue;
    double theta = this.stddev();
    double sqrtT = Math.sqrt(T);
    return u+1.96*theta/sqrtT;
} // high endpoint of 95% confidence interval

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int N = 200;
   int T = 100;
   if (args.length == 1) N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   else if (args.length == 2) {
       N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       T = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); }

   PercolationStats a = new PercolationStats(N, T);
   System.out.print("mean                    = ");
   System.out.println(a.mean());
   System.out.print("stddev                  = ");
   System.out.println(a.stddev());
   System.out.print("95% confidence interval = ");
   System.out.print(a.confidenceLo()); 
   System.out.print(", ");
   System.out.println(a.confidenceHi());
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, I know their difference, but in this case, I don't know how can I use local variable to store that information. I post codes above

Comment: Can you update "Percolation" and "StdRandom" classes as well??

Comment: I post "Percolation" and StdRandom is a standard library from Princeton

Comment: I went through the code.. It consumes lot of memory because you have assigned big matrices (boolean[][] site in Percolation) class. You can keep elements which are only false, if elements are not available in array, u can think that is true.. avoid using premetive arrays and use hashtables to store multi-dimension and insert data which has only false..